# return a list containing elements of another list

Tags: python, list

I need to write an expression and I'm completely stuck. I have part of the code that I think I have written correctly but I'm stick on the rest of it. I need the code to return a new list containing every 3rd element in the list, starting at index 0.

For example: if I have the list `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` I need it to return `[0, 3]`

The code I have so far is:

```
result = []
i = 0
while i < len(L):
    result.append(L[i])
    i = 
return result
```

Can someone please help me figure out what I need the `i =` expression to be for this code to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, you can make use of extended slice notation to make things easier:

```
In [1]: l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [2]: l[::3]
Out[2]: [0, 3]
```

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html):

> Some sequences also support “extended slicing” with a third “step” parameter: a[i:j:k] selects all items of a with index x where x = i + n*k, n >= 0 and i <= x < j.

As for your code sample, you probably need `i = i + 3` or `i += 3` there.

Comment: Could you explain you answer? I don't understand

Comment: @user1816131 yep, gimme a sec

Comment: @user1816131: list slices have *three* slots; start, end and stride. Compare this with the arguments to the `range()` function.

Comment: Oh yeah, I always forget about that option in slices. Lev's answer is better than mine by far.

Comment: @user1816131 I expanded the answer a bit, feel free to ask if something needs to be explained further.

Comment: @LevLevitsky Thank you so much, I feel really stupid now I feel I should have know that straight away

Comment: @user1816131 No one knows this straight away. And almost everyone is surprised at some point to learn that slices have a third parameter. Also, not knowing something doesn't make one stupid. Inability to learn does.

Comment: Note that : `l[::3]` is equivalent to  `l[slice(0,len(l),3)]`.

Comment: @Aswini: Not necessarily. `l[::3]` is only guaranteed to be equivalent to `l[slice(None, None, 3)]`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this:

```
result = []
for i in range(0, len(L), 3):
    result.append(L[i])
return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use `enumerate`.

```
[j for i, j in enumerate([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) if i % 3 == 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

this will give tyou an iterable sequence:

```
import itertools

l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
itertools.islice(l, 0, None, 3)
```

to turn it into a list, use the list() function.

```
impiort itertools

def get_sublist(l):
    return list(itertools.islice(l, 0, None, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    python 3.2
    one way:
    >>> [i for i in range(0,len(L),3)]
    [0,3]


    your method:
    result = []
    i = 0
    while i <= len(L):
       result.append(L[i])
       i+=3
    return result
```